# Debugging ASP using Internet Explorer 10 in Windows 8

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, asp-classic

Just started using Windows 8 here at work and I'm trying to debug some classic ASP code.

Anyway, if there's an error on the page I just get a generic "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." in IE10.

Show friendly HTTP errors are turned off.

If I use IE9 on a Windows 7 machine I get the full VBScript compilation error.

Get this same generic error in Chrome and Firefox so I'm not sure what is going on, anyone else encounter this?

Comment: What version of IIS is running on the server?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a 500 HTTP response, an exception happened on the server and you'll need to attach a debugger to the IIS process on the host machine.

To see the exception details in your browser from a remote machine (which it sounds like what your Windows 8 PC is), make sure your web.config file has this setting:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This won't let you debug your code however.